# Selenium Webdriver- How to click "Log In" button in a webpage

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium, tried different methods to click the Login button in a webpage, but ended up with "Unable to locate element: " error.  Appreciate your help on how i can do it correctly.

```html
<form class="LoginForm__Form-gmPGuK fIaXrM" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="InputWrapper__Wrapper-dYpPUc btujOC">
      <label class="Input__Container-evMrUq XWErm"><span class="Input__Label-dTgnUu ikGhjC">Username</span><input class="Input-eXLwAq eqVwiS" name="username" type="text" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" value="" style="font-size: 1.6rem;"></label>
      <p class="InputWrapper__ErrorMessage-bFHpkO jmYdPT">Invalid username</p>
   </div>
   <div class="Password__Wrap-kEDFHF gajvNg">
      <div class="InputWrapper__Wrapper-dYpPUc btujOC"><label class="Input__Container-evMrUq ipuRfT"><span class="Input__Label-dTgnUu ikGhjC">Password</span><input class="Input-eXLwAq eqVwiS" name="password" autocapitalize="off" id="password" type="text" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" value="" style="font-size: 1.6rem;"></label></div>
   </div>
   <div class="LoginForm__Agree-djIMue hEHJaH">By logging in, you agree to our  <a class="LoginForm__Terms-diivNK iYiAkF" href="https://www.EEE.com/yyyyyyy/rr/terms-and-conditions.html" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></div>
   <button class="Button-hYXUXp bTvZVR" type="submit">LOG IN</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Share the code you tried.

Comment: Share the HTML and trial code

Comment: If it works https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with `WebdriverWait`

```
WebElement username= driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
username.sendKeys("dsfs");

WebElement password= driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
password.sendKeys("fsdfdsfs");

WebElement LogInbtn= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='LOG IN']"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(LogInbtn));
LogInbtn.click();
```

If it is in frame then first go to frame and then use above code

Comment: Thanks, Please accept as answer on clicking Right icon below Downvote button